# I have implemented this code to detect incoming call and charging... how can I disable touch for this functionality?

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, touch-event, android-broadcastreceiver, android-touch-event

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private Context mcontext;
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager =
        (TelephonyManager) mcontext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mcontext = context;
        PhoneStateListener callStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                    IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
                    Intent batteryStatus = mcontext.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);

                    int status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
                    boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                        status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

                    if(isCharging==true){
                        Toast.makeText(mcontext,"PLEASE UNPLUG", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        telephonyManager.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
}
```

Comment: where to want to disable touch?

Comment: when the incoming call comes while the phone is charging...

Comment: i dont know how to disable complete touch input by setontouchlistener(null) for the above functionality i implemented and revoke the touch interface after when charging is removed...